# Add Id field to firestore document after new document is created in cloud function

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am creating a new document in cloud function and want this new document to have a field id where id of document matched with the field. But the response does not have the id field with it. Kindly help

```
exports.newPostFromMCQ = functions.firestore
  .document('answers/{answerDocId}')
  .onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
    const newAnswer = snapshot.data();
    
    //Create New Post Document
    await admin
      .firestore()
      .collection('posts')
      .doc()
      .set({
        createdAt: FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
        updatedAt: FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
        postType: 'MCQ',
      })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log('Successfully created new post:', response);
        //add newly generated document id with document itself
        
      });
  });
```

Comment: You can either update the document with the ID after it's added, or you can have the SDK generate the ID before you add the document, making sure the id field is present in the object you provide. Note that the `doc()` method generates the document ID in the returned DocumentReference object.  The ID is generated locally and doesn't access the cloud at all.